# Select second <select> which is in second (next) td

Tags: jquery

I have table, with `tr` and `td`. In every row I have two `td` with a `<select>`. In every row the first `td` has class `jz-pl`, second td has class `jz-en`.

What I want to achieve is to add style to `<select>` in second `<td class="jz-en">` when `<select>` in first `<td class="jz-pl">` change.

Please notice, that I want to do that only in this row, not every element with this class.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("td.jz-pl select").change(function() {
    jQuery(this).next('td.jz-en select').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
});
```

Comment: Please post you html, and try to read you question to see if you can understand it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to traverse up to parent `td` element then use `.next('td.jz-en')` to target immediately following `td` element then use `.find()`/`.children()` to target `select` element.

```
jQuery("td.jz-pl select").change(function() {       
    jQuery(this).closest('td').next('td.jz-en').find('select').css('background-color','red');
});
```

Various traversal methods can be use [`.closest('td')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Alternatively you can traverse up to `tr` then `find()` the desired element.

```
jQuery("td.jz-pl select").change(function() {       
    jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('td.jz-en select').css('background-color','red');
});
```

Comment: As an alternative, I'd go up to the `tr` and not rely on `.next()` as it's too brittle (eg if you add another column between .jz-pl and .jz-en, this code will break).  `$(this).closest("tr").find("td.js-en select")...`   But the concept is the same.